# Problems with encoded special characters using $windows.location and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, url, encoding

I have a javascript code where I do a window.location to an .net mvc action. id is a number e.x. 1234, while name is a name with special character. E.x. "Røed"

```
$window.location = "/mycontroller/myaction/?id=" + query.id + "&name=" + query.name;
```

In fiddler I can see that the request url becomes: 
mydomain.com/controller/action/?id=1234&name=R%C3%B8ed

When I in my ASP.NET MVC controller tries to get the query string values from Request.QueryString, I get something which looks like a double encoded string:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(LandingPage currentPage, string state)
{
    string queryString = Request.QueryString.ToString();
    var cultureName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
```

querystring becomes: "id=1234&name=R%u00f8ed"

As you can see, the encoding from the request url doesn't look the same as the one in asp.net. why?

I need to use the decoded name further in my application (Røed). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can we see more of your controller code?

Comment: I have updated the controller code. I needed to simplify it as it is part of a CMS.

Comment: That controller doesn't look like it has much to do with the URL you're providing it. Please look at my answer for comparison.

Comment: can you update question involving "LandingPage" class

Comment: I can't provide the entire controller code, but the controller purpose is to do a new redirect to the correct application based on different configuration and the querystring. Hence the querystring could include multiple parameters and not only id and name. That's one of the reasons we don't want to have a lot of params into each action in the controller. 

The LandingPage class isn't important for the problem. It is a page class for EpiServer (CMS)

Comment: default asp.net mvc binder do not support "?id=" + encodeURIComponent(query.id) + "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(query.name);" this  to MyAction(LandingPage currentPage, string state) that. That is why i am trying to ask you what  properties that LandingPage class has.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the javascript side (to ensure you encode each part correctly):

```
$window.location = "/mycontroller/action/?id=" + encodeURIComponent(query.id) + "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(query.name);
```

and this on the MVC side:

```
public ActionResult Action(string id, string name)
{

}
```

or, using your example now that you've provided it:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(LandingPage currentPage, string state, string id = null, string name = null)
{
    if (id != null && name != null)
    {
    }
}
```

and then name should be interpreted correctly. Because you're using the QueryString directly, it's the encoded query string.

If you really need to, you can parse the query string using `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(...)` which will give you a `NameValueCollection`, but this isn't the correct way to do things.

Comment: I got the same problem when using encodedURIComponent in the javascript. I can't change the params into the actions, because of our landingPage design

Comment: Why can't you add more parameters? You don't have to specify all parameters in a request, you can do `string name = null` and it will be optional. Otherwise, you'll need to _manually_ parse the query string, which seems somewhat pointless.